# class Form not found in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

```
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">

                    {{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
what is the problem with form tag i have updated composer update and include file in app.php in laravel
```

i m facing this issue in laravel 5.3.31

Comment: Do you have laravelcollective package installed and added to app.php?

Answer (score 2):

Do this, it should fix the issue, also remove the extra `{` before form

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"

 'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],

'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Comment: is there a difference?

Comment: without specifying version will auto detect compatibility

Comment: yea but is there a difference since we know he uses v 5.3?

Comment: no difference but if `less code` works the same no need to add extra code

Comment: 3min  code and  3 hours  searching for solution and Here is  thank you